# MySQL query to get route between 2 lat-lng coordinates

Tags: mysql, node.js, geographic-distance

I'm looking for a query to get the route between two points.

I have this link, let's say:

```
example.com/any? lat1 = 31.0000 & lng1 = 31.0000 & lat2 = 31.0000 & lng2 = 31.0000
```

So inside the function, I want to write a query that goes to the table example,

```
id | lat1    | lng1    | lat2    | lng2     | time | distance_between_inKm
1  | 31.0000 | 31.0000 | 31.0000 | 31.0000   | 30   | 20
```

So now I want to go to the link and get the nearest || Closest* route or row

I'm getting these from link lat1 & lng1 and lat2 & lng2 so I want to get the closest for the two.

So what I want is that I have a table contains static data for polylines and info for 2 points so I want to use them like Google Matrix api but from my server, let's say:

### Update

I tried this query but it ignore the AND:

```
    SELECT id,distance_between,time_between,start_latitude, start_longitude,end_latitude,end_longitude, SQRT(
        POW(69.1 * (start_latitude - 31.908482676577364), 2) +
        POW(69.1 * (35.1666776731924 - start_longitude) * COS(start_latitude / 57.3), 2)) 

AND
        SQRT(
        POW(69.1 * (end_latitude - 31.966051), 2) +
        POW(69.1 * (35.894587 - end_longitude) * COS(end_latitude / 57.3), 2))
        AS distance
    FROM matrix_api USE INDEX (start_latitude,start_longitude,end_latitude,end_longitude,distance_between,time_between) HAVING distance < 0.2 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1;
```

So I want something like that give input 1 and 2 and give me the row that has the 2

Close for the start latlngs and the end latlngs at the same time

### Update

I tried this too, no luck still:

```
    SELECT id,distance_between,time_between,start_latitude, start_longitude,end_latitude,end_longitude, 
SQRT(
    POW(69.1 * (start_latitude - 32.016659), 2) +
    POW(69.1 * (35.727839 - start_longitude) * COS(start_latitude / 57.3), 2) AND

POW(69.1 * (end_latitude - 31.966051), 2) +
    POW(69.1 * (35.894587 - end_longitude) * COS(end_latitude / 57.3), 2)

) 

    AS distance
FROM matrix_api USE INDEX (start_latitude,start_longitude,end_latitude,end_longitude,distance_between,time_between) HAVING distance < 0.2 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1;
```

Sample input:

```
lat1=0.0000 lng1=0.0000
lat2=0.0000 lng2=0.0000
```

Output:

```
The row that I already have in table Distance between: 0.0 And time between: 0.0
```

So inside table we have the lat1 and lng1 lat2 lng2 And distance between. I want to get the row with nearest lat1 lng1 in same time nearest to lat2 lng2. But here the 2 are in same row saved so I want it like Google API Matrix closest distance between inside the row I need or found.

Comment: *it ignore the AND* No. It calculates... logical AND between left and right expressions values.

Comment: Please give a sample input and sample output in a simpler way with what formula you want to apply. Above explanation is bit confusing.

Comment: Sorry I just have so many rows in table with 2 latlngs and some info
I just want to use a query that gives me the nearest row in km with input another 2 latlngs

Like google API matrix distance between but I have it inside the row

Answer (score 0):

A small change in your query:

```
SELECT id,distance_between,time_between
,start_latitude, start_longitude,end_latitude,end_longitude
FROM
( 
 SELECT id,distance_between,time_between
 ,start_latitude, start_longitude,end_latitude,end_longitude,
 SQRT(
 POW(69.1 * (start_latitude - 31.908482676577364), 2) +
 POW(69.1 * (35.1666776731924 - start_longitude) * COS(start_latitude / 57.3), 2)
 ) as startlatlngDistance
 ,SQRT(
 POW(69.1 * (end_latitude - 31.966051), 2) +
 POW(69.1 * (35.894587 - end_longitude) * COS(end_latitude / 57.3), 2))
 AS endlatlngDistance
 FROM matrix_api 
 USE INDEX (start_latitude,start_longitude,end_latitude
 ,end_longitude,distance_between,time_between) 
) as A
WHERE startlatlngDistance < 0.2 AND endlatlngDistance < 0.2 
ORDER BY startlatlngDistance LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I got this Error in query (1248): Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Trying it, Is it too slow or my server? and page lag xd

Comment: I just changed your own query a little, it might work i think.

Comment: Its taking forever even till now btw i have over 70M Rows

Comment: bro try it for 10 rows and then tell me it is working or not.

Comment: The server I'm using is 16v core CPU and 32 GB rams bro this is taking a life to load and then crash the browser or the app Like I'm asking the question for something that actually works on my server not to know its working or not, Indeed this query will work but will I use it? no cuz it will take forever without results